# solve circular dependency in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, circular-dependency, class-transformer

How to solve circular dependency. I have two files one is `conversation.serialization.ts`

```
@Exclude()
export class ConversationSerialization {
  @ApiResponseProperty({ type: () => [MessageSerialization] })
  @Expose({
    groups: [CONVERSATION.FIND_MY, CONVERSATION.FIND_BY_ID],
  })
  @Type(() => MessageSerialization)
  messages: MessageSerialization[];

  constructor(partial: Partial<ConversationSerialization>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

and second is `message.serialization.ts`

```
@Exclude()
export class MessageSerialization {
  @Type(() => ConversationSerialization)
  @ApiResponseProperty()
  @Expose({ groups: [] })
  conversation?: ConversationSerialization;

  constructor(partial: Partial<MessageSerialization>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

Both classes depends on each other and causes circular dependency. I tried to use barrel export for this, but it didn't help a lot. Barrel exports just fix circular dependency in typescript files but in compiled js is still remained. Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

`schema.prisma`

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider     = "prisma-client-js"
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id                          String    @id @default(cuid())
  email                       String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  name                        String    @db.VarChar(255)
  password                    String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  resetPasswordToken          String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  resetPasswordTokenExpiresAt DateTime?

  sentMessages Messages[] @relation("SentMessages")

  seenMessages SeenMessages[]

  sentFriendRequests     FriendsRequest[] @relation("FriendsRequestSender")
  receivedFriendRequests FriendsRequest[] @relation("FriendsRequesReceiver")

  myFriends Friends[] @relation("UserFriends")
  friendsBy Friends[] @relation("UserFriendsBy")

  groupsOwned          Groups[]
  ConversationsOnUsers ConversationsOnUsers[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Friends {
  user      User   @relation("UserFriends", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String
  friend    User   @relation("UserFriendsBy", fields: [friendId], references: [id])
  friendId  String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@id([userId, friendId])
}

model Messages {
  id      String @id @default(cuid())
  message String @db.VarChar(500)

  seenBy SeenMessages[]

  sender   User   @relation(name: "SentMessages", fields: [senderId], references: [id])
  senderId String

  conversation    Conversations @relation(fields: [conversationsId], references: [id])
  conversationsId String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([senderId, conversationsId])
}

model SeenMessages {
  seenBy    User   @relation(fields: [seenById], references: [id])
  seenById  String
  message Messages @relation(fields: [messageId], references: [id])
  messageId String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@id([seenById, messageId])
}

model Conversations {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  isGroup Boolean? @default(false)

  messages             Messages[]
  group                Groups?
  conversationsOnUsers ConversationsOnUsers[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model ConversationsOnUsers {
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String

  conversation    Conversations @relation(fields: [conversationsId], references: [id])
  conversationsId String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@id([userId, conversationsId])
}

model FriendsRequest {
  sender     User   @relation(name: "FriendsRequestSender", fields: [senderId], references: [id])
  senderId   String
  receiver   User   @relation(name: "FriendsRequesReceiver", fields: [receiverId], references: [id])
  receiverId String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@id([senderId, receiverId])
}

model Groups {
  name     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  isPublic Boolean? @default(false)

  owner   User   @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
  ownerId String

  conversation    Conversations @relation(fields: [conversationsId], references: [id])
  conversationsId String        @unique

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@id([ownerId, conversationsId])
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, circular dependency is a sign of poor oop design. You can try to solve it with `forwardRef` (look in the docs), but the best way to solve the issue is to redesign your code

Comment: @Moti forwardRef only works with nest.js modules and these serialization classes is not registered anywhere. In this case it does not work. About code redesign, that would help, but I do not have any ideas how redesign my code smartly

Comment: It is hard to advise something, because I do not know what you want to achieve, but for me it looks like `Conversation` is a parent of `Message` so I do not understand why a message should have a reference to it's parent. Sorry, but I need more information to efficiently help

Comment: @Moti these serialization basically represents db schema (I added prisma schema to my post). Like you can see from the schema there is relations from both sides, so my serialization is also from both sides

Comment: I do not know your needs, but I would recommend to hold just `conversationId` in messages instead of whole `ConversationSerialization`

Comment: @Moti in my db schema I have `Conversations` and `Messages` so this is what my serializers represents. I can get `Messages` from `Conversation` or I can get `Conversations` from `Messages`. There is relation from both sides. Then How to structure my serializers if I wanna get data from both sides? If I leave only `conversationId` then I can't get `Conversation` from `Messages`

Comment: But the problem here is that you are having infinite circular dependency. Let's say you are getting a message. The message has conversation which has messages that again references the same conversation and this conversation again references same messages and so on

Comment: @Moti Yeah I perfectly understand that, but how to fix this without losing relation between serializers